# Wrap PHP with variable into hidden DIV

Tags: php, html

I have a complex script where exact line

```
<?php echo $this->loadTemplate('report'); ?>
```

echoes specific "report" form on page loading.

I try to wrap this line into DIV to save loading of this report on page but make it hidden.

Unfortunately my experiment

```
<?php echo "<div hidden>HIDEME<?php echo $this->loadTemplate('report'); ?></div>"?>
```

just hides but does not "echo".

Thx for any hint to try (if such kind of wrapping of PHP code with DIV is possible)

Comment: You're already in the PHP. Take out the `<?php echo` and concatenate the `$this->loadTemplate('report')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are echoing an opening `<?php` tag. Instead you want to concatenate.

Been a while since I did any PHP, but assuming your `loadTemplate` works, this should do the trick.

```
<?php echo "<div hidden>HIDEME".$this->loadTemplate('report')."</div>"?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already echoing - don't open a second echo, but end/start the echoed strings with quotes and use dots to connect the php-specific part:

```
<?php echo "<div hidden>HIDEME".$this->loadTemplate('report')."</div>" ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you mean that?

```
<?php
echo '<style type="text/css"> .hidden {display:none;} </style>';
echo '<div class="hidden">'.$this->loadTemplate('report').'</div>';
?>
```